# Shall I pray for what I want but I think I do not deserve?

Tags: prayer

I am a student very interested into spirituality and religion. I must admit that I am immensely blessed, God has given me a lot. But still there are some materialistic things that you want in your life, shall I pray to god to give me that? I know whatever God does, does for my own good, but I want it badly. Also, I feel that I do not deserve that particular thing, because I have not worked as hard as others do to get it. But I am a great believer in god and I know he can do anything. Shall I pray without any guilt?

Comment: Like any library, Christianity Stack Exchange offers great information, but does not offer personalized advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your pastor, priest, or other trustworthy counselor.

Comment: @Nigel J Thank you, I will keep that in mind :)

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  To understand how we are different to other sites, please take our Tour: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question of whether you could pray without any guilt **depends on the state of your conscience**. From what you say, it appears you do have twinges of guilt, causing you to hold back from that prayer. Perhaps you are seeking validation from others, but nobody here can give you that. Only God can either accept or reject your prayer request. The question really boils down to, ***"Given that this is a Christianity site, how does a Christian know that any prayer request conforms to God's will for prayer?"***

Christians are clear from what Jesus said and did that it's essential to conform to God's will in all of our life. That is why Jesus taught us to pray as the point of first importance, "Our Father in heaven, hallowed be thy name; thy kingdom come, thy will be done on earth, as it is in heaven" (Matthew 6:9-10). Only after that are we to pray for daily needs, forgiveness, deliverance etc. Just before going to the cross, Jesus prayed, "Yet not as I will, but as you will." And, "My Father, if it is not possible for this cup to be taken away unless I drink it, may your will be done" (Matthew 26:39 & 42).

Your desire (for whatever it is) seems very great, though you know you haven't worked as hard for it as some others have. Are you supposing that God might make it easier for you to attain this? Well, why should he? Is this thing going to advance the cause of his kingdom and his righteousness? After all, Jesus said, ***"Seek first the kingdom of God and his righteousness, and all these other things will be added to you"*** (Matthew 6:33). Necessary things, like food, water and clothing - not luxuries, or vain things (to do with power or prestige).

The apostle John wrote to those who believe in the name of the Son of God (Christians, in other words) that we have confidence in approaching God in prayer "that ***we may ask anything according to his will, he hears us***, and if we know that he hears us - whatever we ask - we know that we have what we asked of him" (1 John 5:13-15). **Only when we ask in Jesus' name for something that is God's will for us, and for his glory, do we know that he hears us favourably.**

If what you desire is nothing that will contribute towards the kingdom of God and his righteousness, and thus be in God's will for you, then it might be better to devote yourself to learning how to ascertain God's will, and then start doing it as your guiding direction in life. **Then you will have a clear conscience, and  then you will discover the lovely truth of 1 John 5:13-15.**

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It was beautiful :)

Comment: @Lesley, don't post something that is not relevant to this site.